# Not able to redirect on server using AngulaJS and MVC C#

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm writing this simple code in html:-

```
<a id="{{L.ID}}" target="_blank" href="/Home/RedirectToMaterialView?MaterialTypeID={{L.MaterialTypeID}}&SearchListID={{L.SearchListID}}&Category={{L.Category}}" style="cursor:pointer">Open</a>
```

Now this goes to my HomeController and works perfect in my local machine, where I redirect it to some other actionlink. c# controller actionresult is like this:-

```
public ActionResult RedirectToMaterialView(string MaterialTypeID, string SearchListID, string Category)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchListID))
        {
            dbundle.MaterialFetchID = Convert.ToInt32(SearchListID);
            dbundle.MaterialIndicator = Convert.ToInt32(MaterialTypeID);
            dbundle.MaterialFor = Convert.ToString(Category);

            string queryString = string.Empty;

            TempData["DBundle"] = dbundle;
            switch (dbundle.MaterialFor)
            {
                case "Class":
                    switch (dbundle.MaterialIndicator)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            TempData["ClassMaterialHeading"] = Constants.EBook;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            TempData["ClassMaterialHeading"] = Constants.Notes;
                            break;
                        default:
                            TempData["ClassMaterialHeading"] = "";
                            break;
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction(Constants.ClassMaterial, new { id= dbundle.MaterialFetchID, MatFor =dbundle.MaterialFor});
                case "Degree":
                    switch (dbundle.MaterialIndicator)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            TempData["DegreeMaterialHeading"] = Constants.EBook;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            TempData["DegreeMaterialHeading"] = Constants.Notes;
                            break;                            
                        default:
                            TempData["DegreeMaterialHeading"] = "";
                            break;
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction(Constants.DegreeMaterial, new { id = dbundle.MaterialFetchID, MatFor = dbundle.MaterialFor });                    
                default:
                    return RedirectToAction(Constants.School);
            }                
        }
        else
            return RedirectToAction(Constants.Degree);
    }
```

But when I run this code on server. It's redirecting to a blank page.

[image: This appears insted of redirecting]

I don't know what's creating problem. Maybe I'm missing something in the link. But I can't figure out what's the problem on server which is not on my machine.
Help Appreciated.

Comment: So is the redirection not happening? Is the redirection page incorrect? Is the content missing? Not quite understanding what problem you're having. Are all of those case conditions necessary to reproduce the problem? Removing some of them would help us follow your code.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Jasen. Actually the redirect is happening but I guess correct path is not getting hit. I've modified the question and removed case conditions for better understanding.